Azure Tenant setup for .NET Blazor WASM calling Web API + Microsoft Graph
Overview: I would like to create a solution for an organization using MSAL. The company seems to have users under a single Azure AD tenant. My solution should use a Blazor WASM UI with a .NET API running server side. I want to authenticate the users for the organization in the UI and pass the token to the API where it will call Microsoft Graph(for email data mostly).
Question: What should my Azure Tenant setup look like? Entra Id or Azure AD B2C?
Attempted methods and further information: I have setup (and somewhat got working) a regular Entra ID tenant. I have also tried Azure AD B2C, but ran into the issue where the API couldn't delegate permissions to the Graph API. Ideally this will be somewhat easy to package and serve to the organization for them to manage.

Keep it simple and use the existing Azure Entry Id tenant. No point in using  B2C for your scenario.

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to fetch emails data of all users or single user using Microsoft Graph in .NET?

Hi @BraydonGriffith Any update?

@Sridevi Thank you for your response! This is very helpful. I have currently implemented up to about the point you have reached in your response. Entra ID seems to clearly be the choice, and as Peter Bons has mentioned, this is probably correct for development but the registrations should be done in the existing organizations AD tenant. (Something I don't have experience in but should have some assistance from the Orgs IT) I am fetching email data for a single user at a time, but the implementation should work for multiple users in the single organization. Thank you again for your help.

I agree with @Peter Bons, it is best to use existing Microsoft Entra ID tenant rather than opting for Azure AD B2C.

Azure AD B2C is primarily intended for scenarios where you need to authenticate external or consumer users like social accounts.
Microsoft Entra ID (formerly known as Azure AD) is designed for organizational identity management and will be a better fit for your scenario, where the users are within a single organization.

In my case, I referred this GitHub sample for enabling Blazor WASM UI to sign in users and call Microsoft Graph API. Initially, I registered one application and granted Mail.Read permission of Delegated type in it with consent as below:

In Authentication tab, I added https://localhost:44314/authentication/login-callback as redirect URI under SPA platform, along with logout URL:

After cloning the  GitHub sample, I opened WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph/blazorwasm-calls-MS-graph path and updated below code files:
UserProfileBase.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace blazorwasm_calls_MS_graph.Pages
{
    public class UserProfileBase : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        protected User _user = new User();
        protected List<Message> _messages = new List<Message>();
        protected string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await GetUserProfile();
            await GetUserMessages();
        }

        private async Task GetUserProfile()
        {
            try
            {
                var request = GraphClient.Me.Request();
                _user = await request.GetAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"User Profile fetched: {_user.DisplayName}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMessage = $"Error fetching user profile: {ex.Message}";
                Console.WriteLine(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        private async Task GetUserMessages()
        {
            try
            {
                var request = GraphClient.Me.Messages.Request();
                var messages = await request.Top(10).GetAsync(); // Fetch top 10 email messages

                if (messages == null || !messages.CurrentPage.Any())
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "No email messages found.";
                    Console.WriteLine("No email messages found.");
                }
                else
                {
                    _messages = messages.CurrentPage.ToList();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Fetched {_messages.Count} email messages.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMessage = $"Error fetching email messages: {ex.Message}";
                Console.WriteLine(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
    }

UserProfile.Razor:
@page "/profile"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
@inherits UserProfileBase

<h3>User Profile</h3>

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Error:</strong> @ErrorMessage
    </div>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Property</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>DisplayName</td>
            <td>@_user.DisplayName</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>UserPrincipalName</td>
            <td>@_user.UserPrincipalName</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

<h3>Email Messages</h3>

@if (_messages == null || !_messages.Any())
{
    <p>No email messages found.</p>
}
else
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var message in _messages)
        {
            @if (message != null && message.From != null && message.From.EmailAddress != null)
            {
                <li>
                    <strong>@message.Subject</strong><br />
                    From: @message.From.EmailAddress.Address<br />
                    Sent: @message.SentDateTime?.ToString("g")<br />
                    Body Preview: @message.BodyPreview
                </li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li>Invalid message data.</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
}

When I ran the project now and visited https://localhost:44314 in browser, it asked me to sign in like this:

After successful login, it showed signed-in user's email data in Profile page as below:

